# How to get the start and end times of a day

Tags: c#, datetime

In my C# app, I pass a string variable that is of format yyyymmdd-yyyymmdd that represents a from and to date. I want to get the start and end times for these dates respectively. Currently I have the below code but was wondering if there was more of an elegant solution?

So for pdr = 20090521-20090523 would get "20090521 00:00:00" and "20090523 23:59:59"

```
private void ValidateDatePeriod(string pdr, out DateTime startDate, 
                                out DateTime endDate)
{
    string[] dates = pdr.Split('-');

    if (dates.Length != 2)
    {
        throw new Exception("Date period is of incorrect format");
    }

    if (dates[0].Length != 8 || dates[1].Length != 8)
    {
        throw new Exception("Split date periods are of incorrect format");
    }

    startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dates[0] + " 00:00:00", 
        "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss", null);
    endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dates[1] + "23:59:59", 
        "yyyyMMdd HH::mm:ss", null);
}
```

Comment: As others have stated, EndOfDay is probably an unnecessary and inaccurate construct, as it doesn't have a definite point in time, except perhaps tomorrow's StartOfDay.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

I am surprised to see how an [***incorrect answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/903365/437979) received so many upvotes:

[image: Wrong value]

The correct version would be as follows:

```
public static DateTime StartOfDay(this DateTime theDate)
{
    return theDate.Date;
}

public static DateTime EndOfDay(this DateTime theDate)
{
    return theDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
}
```

Comment: as mentioned by @Chris F Carroll, -1 tick may not be correct also.

Comment: @liang, he mentioned: "AddTick(-1) only works under the convention that there are no time intervals smaller than a tick". Is there a smaller time inverval in .NET?

Comment: He gave example when working with database. Database implementation varies. When in those scenarios, -1 tick may not be the end of the day anymore. At least, should not be relied on to use equal comparison. In the same spirit of floating numbers, you can't say what is the biggest floating number that is smaller than an integer reliably which depends on implementation details. Rather greater/less is probably better.

Comment: I like this solution as it is simple.  As @liang said, it could be simpler by not  using AddTicks(-1).  For instance: `(time >= startOfDay && time < nextDay)` .. Although the poster was asking how to get the end of a day.

Comment: @breez how does the suggested line of code solve that problem? You subtract 1 tick then you still add 1 day's worth of ticks and exceed the max value anyway. Just add a simple check. Jeez.

Comment: This gives local timezone when the parameter is DateTimeOffset, what if I want the original timezone from DateTimeOffset?

Answer (score 49):

You could define two extension methods somewhere, in a utility class like so :

```
public static DateTime EndOfDay(this DateTime date)
{
    return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);
}

public static DateTime StartOfDay(this DateTime date)
{
    return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

And then use them in code like so :

```
public DoSomething()
{
    DateTime endOfThisDay = DateTime.Now.EndOfDay();
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but incorrect. Please see the screenshot I provided as to see why.

Comment: Indeed. Use Anar Khalilov's one, it's better.

Comment: Can we just do 9999999 for the milliseconds? This should produce the same result as @anarkhalilov

Comment: @IgorK, of course you could add 7 nines. Even though unlikely, but what if in the future .NET Framework designers decide 7 is not enough and make it 10. Still it probably will not crash your code, but why take risks, no?

Comment: @anarkhalilov My bad, it won't let me anyway. I should have tried first. When creating a new DateTime object, if won't let you specify milliseconds over 999.

Answer (score 29):

If you are only worried about .Net precision...

```
startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dates[0], "yyyyMMdd");
endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dates[1], "yyyyMMdd").AddTicks(-1).AddDays(1);
```

You really don't need to concatenate extra values onto the string for the time portion.

---

As an addendum, if you are using this for a query against, for example, a database...

```
startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dates[0], "yyyyMMdd");
endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dates[1], "yyyyMMdd").AddDays(1);
```

With a query of...

```
WHERE "startDate" >= @startDate AND "endDate" < @endDate
```

Then the precision issues noted in the comments won't really matter.  The **endDate** in this case would not be part of the range, but the outside boundary.

Comment: NB: if you are working with a database, you probably have to read the small print on the database's accuracy for 'end of day'. The example I hit was SQL Server DateTime type. It's accurate to about 3 milliseconds so end of day becomes .AddMilliseconds(-3)

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll Personally, I prefer to use `dtm >= start && dtm < end` where end is the date you are looking for something before.

Comment: I think you've made me realise that 'end of the day' is in fact a non-existent notion, and hence We're Doing It Wrong.

Using `< end` doesn't address the precision issue either, e.g.:
`Select Case When Cast('20140101 23:59:59.999' as DateTime) < Cast('20140102' as DateTime) Then 'I have millisecond precision' Else 'I cannot tell the difference' End`

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll In this case `end` is really before the beginning of the next day.  If you're matching against records in a table, your match wouldn't happen in that case either.

Comment: What about if the value is `01/01/9999 00:00:00.000`? That would blow up.

Comment: Adding the ticks first would alleviate that problem:
`endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dates[1], "yyyyMMdd").AddTicks(-1).AddDays(1);`

Answer (score 18):

The `DateTime` object has a property called `Date` which will return just the date portion.  (The time portion is defaulted to 12:00 am).

I would recommend as a more elegant solution (IMHO) that if you want to allow any datetime on the last day, then you add 1 day to the date, and compare to allow times greater than or equal to the start date, but strictly less than the end date (plus 1 day).

```
// Calling code.  beginDateTime and endDateTime are already set.
// beginDateTime and endDateTime are inclusive.
// targetDateTime is the date you want to check.
beginDateTime = beginDateTime.Date;
endDateTime = endDateTime.Date.AddDays(1);

if ( beginDateTime <= targetDateTime &&
     targetDateTime < endDateTime )
   // Do something.
```

Comment: i was wanting to return 2 datetimes from parsing a string, so the calling method could then use these dates to query my db.

Comment: @Matt: your advice is particularly sound if times can have a sub-second resolution.

Answer (score 16):

```
public static class DateTimeExtension {        
    public static DateTime StartOfTheDay(this DateTime d) => new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day, 0, 0,0);
    public static DateTime EndOfTheDay(this DateTime d) => new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day, 23, 59,59);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I use the following in C#

```
public static DateTime GetStartOfDay(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
public static DateTime GetEndOfDay(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);
}
```

Then in MS SQL I do the following:

```
if datepart(ms, @dateEnd) = 0
   set @dateEnd = dateadd(ms, -3, @dateEnd)
```

This will result in MS SQL time of 23:59:59.997 which is the max time before becoming the next day.

You could simply use:

```
new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);
```

Which will work in MS SQL, but this is not as accurate in .Net side.

Answer (score 4):

That's pretty much what I would do, with some small tweaks (really no big deal, just nitpicking):

- The `TryParse()`/`TryParseExact()` methods should be used which return `false` instead of throwing exceptions.
- `FormatException` is more specific than `Exception`
- No need to check for Length == 8, because `ParseExact()`/`TryParseExact()` will do this
- `"00:00:00"` and `"23:59:59"` are not needed
- return `true`/`false` is you were able to parse, instead of throwing an exception (remember to check value returned from this method!)

Code:

```
private bool ValidateDatePeriod(string pdr, out DateTime startDate, 
                        out DateTime endDate)
{
   string[] dates = pdr.Split('-');

   if (dates.Length != 2)
   {
       return false;
   }

   // no need to check for Length == 8 because the following will do it anyway
   // no need for "00:00:00" or "23:59:59" either, I prefer AddDays(1)

   if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(dates[0], "yyyyMMdd", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out startDate))
      return false;

   if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(dates[1], "yyyyMMdd", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out endDate))
      return false;

   endDate = endDate.AddDays(1);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comments. good to know i was on the right track and grateful for the tweaks

Answer (score 3):

I think we're doing it wrong. There is no such thing as the end of the day. `AddTick(-1)` only works under the convention that there are no time intervals smaller than a tick. Which is implementation dependent. Admittedly the question comes with a reference implementation, namely the .Net Framework `DateTime` class, but still we should take this as a clue that the function we really want is not `EndOfDay()` but `StartOfNextDay()`

```
public static DateTime StartOfNextDay(this DateTime date)
{
    return date.Date.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: Why don't we do it AddSeconds(-1), instead of Add Ticks? Last second of the day is accurate enough for most scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

The issue above regarding the few milliseconds can be resolved by querying the database with the next day's start date.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM temp WHERE createdDate >= fromDate AND createdDate < toDate
```

Using the extension methods below you could set the from and to dates to:

```
DateTimeOffset fromDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.StartOfDay();
DateTimeOffset toDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.EndOfDay();
```

```
public static class DateExtentions
{
    public static DateTimeOffset StartOfDay(this DateTimeOffset dateTime)
    {
        return new DateTimeOffset(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0, dateTime.Offset);
    }

    public static DateTimeOffset EndOfDay(this DateTimeOffset dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.StartOfDay().AddDays(1);
    }

    public static DateTimeOffset StartOfMonth(this DateTimeOffset dateTime)
    {
        return new DateTimeOffset(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, dateTime.Offset);
    }

    public static DateTimeOffset EndOfMonth(this DateTimeOffset dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.StartOfMonth().AddMonths(1);
    }

    public static DateTimeOffset StartOfYear(this DateTimeOffset dateTime)
    {
        return new DateTimeOffset(dateTime.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, dateTime.Offset);
    }

    public static DateTimeOffset EndOfYear(this DateTimeOffset dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.StartOfYear().AddYears(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server (version 2008 R2 tested) this ranges works.

StarDate '2016-01-11 00:00:01.990'
EndDate '2016-01-19 23:59:59.990'

Seems like ticks is greater that the last second of day and automatically round to next day. So i test and works, i made a dummy table with two dates for check what values is sql server catching and inserting in the stored procedure those parameters.

Answer (score -3):

In Java 8, you can do it using LocalDate as follows:

```
    LocalDate localDateStart = LocalDate.now();
    Date startDate = Date.from(localDateStart.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

    LocalDate localDateEnd = localDateStart.plusDays(1);
    Date endDate = Date.from(localDateEnd.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Comment: this is a c# post...