# SQL Datagrid Filtering in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, gridview, filter

I have a connected SQL Database in Visual Studio and am displaying its content in a Grid.
I created a Dropdown menu with the column names as selectable options and a text field to filter for specific content, e.g., DropDown = "Start" - Textfield = 14.03.2015 = Filter Column "Start" for each entry that contains "14.03.2015" - and display it in the Grid.

I'm basically done with that part. The only problem left that I'm facing is whenever I enter a date - e.g., 14.03.2015 it only displays dates which start at 00:00:00 - the other entries that do not start at 00:00:00 are ignored and I can't figure out how to modify this to work properly.

The Grid looks like this:
http://abload.de/img/untitled123yqkyn.png

And I am using the following C# code to filter:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FilterExpression = string.Empty;

    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("Start"))
    {
        FilterExpression = string.Format("Start  = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("End"))
    {
        FilterExpression = string.Format("End  = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("Creation Time"))
    {
        FilterExpression = string.Format("DateTimeCreated = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("Last Modified"))
    {
        FilterExpression = string.Format("LastModifiedTime = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        FilterExpression = string.Concat(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, " Like '%{0}%'");
    }

    SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Clear();
    SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add(new ControlParameter(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, "TextBox1", "Text"));
    SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = FilterExpression;
}
```

Excuse the quality of the code, i'm completly new to C# and for that matter programming itself.
I hope that there is someone able to help me.

Comment: To clean up your code, think about using an `enum` for your DropDownList. Also, use a switch statement instead of all those `if else` statements.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I will make sure to clean my code up right after i got it to work properly.

Comment: I would also recommend naming your objects something. Button1, DropDownList1 are useless and becomes a total nightmare when you get more than a few controls on a given screen.

Comment: Well, i only have two buttons, one textfield and one DropDownMenu. There wont be more functionality than there currently is so i think that i'm fine as is. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Is it possible to run some code which will take the specified date e.g. 15/03/2015 and then find the start and end of that day period e.g. 15:03:2015 00:00:01 and 15:03:2015 23:59:59 perhaps store as a tuple, and then bring back every result which is within that tuples range?

Comment: Start and end of a day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902789/how-to-get-the-start-and-and-end-times-of-a-day check if record's date is within range http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781611/how-to-know-if-a-datetime-is-between-a-daterange-in-c-sharp

Comment: Do you know of a way to modify my code without changing it in its whole? I mean i am already getting some values, i just need it to modify so that i get all the values of the given day, not only the ones beginning at 00:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get date filtering (and sorting) to work with datagridview controls was to set the column type explicitly to DateTime.  You can do this in the designer or dynamically as you add the column, using typeof(DateTime), like this:

```
column.ValueType = typeof(DateTime);
```

If you don't do this then the filtering and sorting treat the column as being plain text.

Comment: I'm a bit lost at the moment. What would be the necessary changes in my code? I generate my Grid in .aspx I'm already getting the Dates but only the ones that start at exactly 00:00:00. I'm sure that there is an easy way but i just can't figure it out.

Comment: Enable sorting on your grid, sort by a date column.  If the dates sort "properly", i.e. in date order then it's already a date column.  If the dates sort alphanumerically, then this is a text column and needs changing.  Having said all of this I think your problem is probably down to the way you are filtering, as discussed above?